# How can I merge five mkv files I've created in OBS Studio?

Tags: video, software-recommendation, conversion, transitions, mkv

I used OBS Studio to create five recordings.

Now I need to submit them as just one file on YouTube, so my five .mkv files has to be merged into just one file.

Can it be done in OBS Studio, if so how?
(I didn't manage to do find a way)

Are there any other free tool to download or use online that can fix this in an easy and controllable way?
(Preferable with the possibility of transition effects, like in this [Premiere Pro demonstation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w2-RQxOw2Xg) if possible)

Comment: OBS is not made for editing. If you're looking for the quickest, free way, check out ffmpeg. You should have some experience using the terminal though. If not, Premiere has a free trial as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And yes, if OBS can't do it, I'm looking for something that can. Also it should be with a easy to use graphical UI.

Comment: In that case, ffmpeg is out of the picture. You can try the free trial of Premiere and use something like Filmora or any free software. There are a bunch of threads on here for free editing software, you should definitely find something there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely not a problem. You can do this with MKVToolNix (specifically with it's GUI, since that is what you have requested).

I am on Debian GNU/Linux, if you use something different, your screenshots will differ, do not worry about it.

First start the application:

[image: Empty MKVMerge]

Add the very first file to it:

[image: File added]

Now you will need to add or drop the other files.

Doing so you will get a question of what to do with the files you've added:
Select "Append to an existing source file".

[image: Select Append]

[image: Append Several Files]

Now you only need to provide the name of the output file and press "Start multiplexing".

[image: Start multiplexing]

Comment: Thanks this program worked really well...

Answer (score 1):

In case you will be unable to use MKVToolsNix for whatever reason, there is an older tool which is able to append files quite well: AVIDemux.

The process is trivial. Start the program and open your first file.

[image: Virgin AVIDemux]
[image: AVIDemux with one file open]

You then select append from menu and select files that you want to append.

[image: Append menu item]
[image: Several appended files]

That is it. Now you simply save the output. Take a note that the video and audio streams are set to copy.

[image: Save menu]